# Dlookup a value in a table then multiply it with a value in form field X = value in the form field Y

Tags: ms-access-2007

Hello I am using MS Access 2007

I have a table called Extraction Line it is similar to an order line table , within this table are the two fields of concern:

Field: Tonnage:Number data type

Field: worth:Currency data type

What I want to happen is

As soon a user enters the tonnage value

In the afterupdate event for the tonnage field a Dlookup will
look at the Resource table and find the Price field (currency data type)
It then multiplies the Resource table Price value with the tonnage amount field (e.g) $50 x 5 etc, the $250 value is then added to the worth field.

So far I cannot even get success on using dlookup to get a value from the resource table

My code is in the extraction line form at the afterupdate event for the tonnage field:

```
Private Sub Tonnage_AfterUpdate()

Dim X As Currency


X = DLookup("[Price]", "[Resource]", "Atomic Number" = "076")  

'X= Nz(DLookup("[Price]", "[Resource]", "Atomic Number" = "076"), 0)

'X = DLookup("[Price]", "[Resource]", "[Atomic number] = Form![Atomic number]") * [Worth]
```

I wanted to test the simple part of get a value first before doing the multiply and the rest of the requirements but keep getting Null value errors.

I think I am getting Null value errors due to this explanation
[Null Value is due to...](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?401834-Database-Why-do-I-get-the-error-quot-Invalid-use-of-Null-quot-when-using-field-values)

But of course there will be no value or nothing there as I want dlookup to go get the value first then carry out the maths.

Prior to this way I tried various validation rules within the Extraction Line form but received ?Name errors.

What is the best way to achieve the above. If I can get help to point me in the right direction I can go away and attempt this.

Comment: Added this to the control source of the worth form field:=DLookUp("[Price]","[Resource]")    . That pulls the first record price value from the resource table. Now working on telling the dlookup that the value must be where the atomic number = extraction line ID and extraction line ID = atomic number as each extraction line has 2 primary keys the atomic number + and extraction id  this one failed due to error expected list separator or ) . =DLookUp("[Price]","[Resource]","[Atomic Number] ="'[Extraction ID] And [Extraction ID] = [Atomic Number]'")*[tonnage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Private Sub Tonnage_AfterUpdate()
''It is probably best not to use Currency when you do not know what will
''be returned
Dim varX As Variant

varX = Nz(DLookup("[Price]", "[Resource]", "[Atomic Number] = 076"),0) * [Worth]
```

If you want to refer to the look-up as a field or control and [Atomic Number] is a numeric field:

```
varX = Nz(DLookup("[Price]", "[Resource]", "[Atomic Number] = " _
          & MyNumber),0) * [Worth]
```

In parts:

```
varX = DLookup("[Price]", "[Resource]", "[Atomic Number] = " & MyNumber)

If varX > 0 then
    MyAnswer = VarX * Me.Worth
End If
```

Comment: See the comment in my post i am now trying to tell dlookup this go to resource table, lookup resource worth where the resource worth price is equal to the dual primary key attributes for a one record.  As the extraction line has a dual primary key of resource tables atomic number and the mine extractions extraction ID. I have tried this: =DLookUp("[Price]","[Resource]","[Atomic Number] ="'[Extraction ID] And [Extraction ID] = [Atomic Number]'")*[tonnage].

Comment: I am afraid that is a little fuzzy. If you have a continuous form, this idea will not work. If you have a single form, put the control name outside the quotes, so something like: `=DLookUp("[Price]","[Resource]","[Atomic Number] =" & [ExtractionID])`

Comment: Are you saying that both the form and the lookup table have fields/controls extraction id and atomic number? If so, both go outside the quotes: `=DLookUp("[Price]","[Resource]","[Atomic Number] =" & [Atomic Number] & " And ExtractionID=" & [ExtractionID])`

Comment: Ok table resource has PK of Atomic number, table mine Extraction has PK of extraction ID.  Think of resource table as product table and mine extraction table as the customer table equivalent. The extraction Line table is the equivalent of the order line table so the PK for each record as 1 record = 1 order is made up of the atomic number PK from resource table and extraction ID from the mine extraction table.

Comment: I am trying to tell the worth column in the extraction line table to look at the resource table and then take the value associated with that resource. 1 resource is present in many order lines via the PK setup. So dlookup must look at the atomic number where it is equal to the extraction line ID and vice versa as i dont know if i have to tell the where clause to look at both  as in [Atomic Number] ="'[Extraction ID] And [Extraction ID] = [Atomic Number] that way I will get the exact price of the resource record instead as tested with the dlookup that now works the first record.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18412/discussion-between-remou-and-user1655231)